# No Output in Console from Swift Debug Messages in Expo React Native iOS Module

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, debugging, expo

I'm working on an Expo - React Native project and have created a native iOS module in Swift. I want to output debug messages from Swift to the console for development purposes.

I've tried using:

```
print("Debug message")
```

and

```
import OSLog
let logger = Logger()
logger.info("Logging test")
```

However, I'm not seeing any output in my console.

Additionally, I followed the debugging advice from [Expo's documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/debugging/runtime-issues/#production-app-is-crashing) and checked for logs in the Apple Console, but I didn't find any relevant messages.

Environment:

Expo version: SDK 50
Testing on: Physical Device
iOS version: 16.0

Has anyone encountered this issue or have suggestions on how to properly output debug messages from Swift in this setup? Is there a specific configuration I might be missing?